# How to keep only three digits from a string in excel?

Tags: excel

How do I automatically keep only three digits from a string and apply it to a list while not exceeding 5 decimal points as well as rounding the numbers?

Example:

0.645945 --> 0.646

0.0003452 --> 0.00035

0.000071533 -->0.00007

Comment: And how you tried to do this??? What errors you have when you tried??? We are not a resource site, we help you with you try to do. Please read this [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I tried all the tools within excel, but with no avail. I think it has to be done by vba, but I wanted to make sure before i run into it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a set of numbers starting from B2, highlight the range and proceed as follows:-

(1) Set a default format of three decimal places.

(2) Apply a conditional format rule:-

```
=ABS(B2)<0.1
```

and set four decimal places if this applies.

(3) Apply a conditional format rule:-

```
=ABS(B2)<0.01
```

and set five decimal places if this applies.

As pointed out by @Scott Craner, the second rule must take precedence. One way to achieve this is to put the second rule first and tick the 'stop if true' box in Manage Rules.

[image]

Comment: FWIW You will  need to put them in priority of the smallest to the largest.  The `=ABS(A1)<0.0001` will need to have the first priority then `=ABS(A1)<0.001` and so forth. Because .001 < .1

Comment: Yes I agree, so I think the rule with the smallest value has to come last in 'Manage rules' if you don't tick 'stop if true' or first if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula based solution that will work. The final formula is pretty long, so I broke it into it's parts so you can understand it better.

The point of this solution is it leaves you with the exact number you are looking for and not a formatted display of the number.

[image]

1. B2 = `=TEXT(A2,".00000")`
2. C2 = `=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"0",""))`
3. D2 = `==CHOOSE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"0","")),100,1000,10000,100000,1000000)`
4. E2 = `=ROUND(LEFT(B2,C2+4)*D2,1)/D2`
5. F2 = `=ROUND(LEFT(TEXT(A2,".00000"),LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"0",""))+4)*CHOOSE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"0","")),100,1000,10000,100000,1000000),1)/CHOOSE(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"0","")),100,1000,10000,100000,1000000)`

I am sure there are ways to mathematically simply it even more, but this works as is **for values with 4 or less 0 after the decimal**

Answer (score 0):

Right click -> Format cells and choose number and the decimal places for the cells you want. Or do you want to do this in vba?

Ok like this then =ROUND(A1,INT(3-LOG(A1,10)))

Comment: i want it to apply automatically for a long list of numbers. The problem is that the decimals vary from number to number.

Expample:

[0.985134 --> three decimals 0.985]     

[0.0045236 --> five decimals 0.00452]

      -PS: the numbers should always come out with decimals between 3 and 5 since their values are all bellow 1

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
Do a round of the value with decimal point based on the log of the number
=ROUND(A1,INT(3-LOG(A1,10)))